# jquery photo gallery, photos from database?

Tags: php, jquery, database

I really need some help with my coding since i'm stuck with a problem I can't seem to solve.

I am currently working with a jquery gallery plugin, but instead of having the images in a folder on the server, I'd like to link to a database, and get them from a php script.
So far I've got this:

```
<?php

$dblink = mysql_connect("localhost", "mmd4a201105", "*******");
if (!$dblink)
{
echo "Forbindelse til database kunne ikke etableres".mysql_error();
exit;
}

$db = mysql_select_db ("mmd4a201105");
if (!$db)
{
echo "Databasen kunne ikke vælges".mysql_error();
exit;
}


$sql_streng = "select titel, navn, mail, tekst, fotonavn from foto";

$resultat = mysql_query ($sql_streng, $dblink);
$antal_raekker = mysql_num_rows($resultat);

if ($antal_raekker == 0)
{
echo "Der er ingen fotos at vise!";
}
else
{
while ($raekke = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat))
{
echo "<img src=\"fotos/$raekke[fotonavn]\" alt=\"fotos/$raekke[fotonavn]\" width=\"75px\" height=\"75px\" title=\"$raekke[titel] /><br><br>";

}
}

mysql_close ($dblink);
?>
```

The gallery currently only displays the first image in the database table but I like it to display all images on the database... loop function perhaps, I'm not sure that's what the term is called?

Appreciate any help, and sorry if it's a bit confusing. I'll gladly specify anything required. :)

Comment: If you `echo` the value of `$antal_raekker` what do you get? Your `while` loop should loop through all the results of the database query (so if you're getting one row output there may only be one row).

Comment: I'm not sure I did it right, but when I echo the $antal_raekker value I get a blank area with this code: 1717171717171717171717171717171717.
Okay, but I just checked my database on myphp, and there are plenty og photos uploaded there... I just don't get why it only displays the first one of them on the site.... Where can I adjust the php, so it displays all the photos available in the database instead of the first one only? :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like you are getting the number `17` seventeen times, meaning you `echo`d the `$antal_raekker` variable inside a loop (I suspect inside the `while` loop, meaning it did iterate seventeen times). When I debug a variable I generally but an `exit;` just after it so nothing else gets output. Can you paste in the resultant HTML to your question?

Comment: So where should I exactely put an "exit;"? Sorry I'm not so very experienced with php yet, so I'd be so glad if you explained things very basically ;)
I did not get your very last line... Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: I was just saying that when you want to see the output of a variable I do this: `echo $antal_raekker; exit;` which stops the script from running right after the variable is output. That means that you can easily find the outputted variable because it will be at the bottom of the page when you view the source. I also asked to see the HTML output from your PHP script because it seems like the `while` loop does run seventeen times so there should be seventeen `<img>` tags in the source code (perhaps it's a CSS issue that is hiding the others or something).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot!
When I put that echo line in, the element I put it in is just blank... I don' t know if I do something wrong? I just put it in under the other echo-line exactely as you wrote it.
All right here is the source code:

Comment: You can view it here: http://mmd4a201105.keaweb.dk/galleri3/index.php

Comment: So here's a tip from programming 101. If you're having issues always check the output of your script. Once I opened the source of you page it was quite obvious that there is an error (and since PHP error handling is pretty good it will help tons). I added an answer to your question that should help you resolve the problem. Your loop **is** working, but the code within the loop has errors that have to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
while ($raekke = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat))
{

    if ($antal_raekker == 0){
        echo "Der er ingen fotos at vise!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img src=\"fotos/$raekke[fotonavn]\" alt=\"fotos/$raekke[fotonavn]\" width=\"75px\" height=\"75px\" title=\"$raekke[titel] /><br><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed that but didn't have any effect... Still only shows one photo.... :( I know for sure there are more arrays in the database!

Comment: Try removing 'mysql_close ($dblink);' and tell is that doing trick

Comment: I removed it, nothing happened? :)
Thanks, in advance though... Appreciate your effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is with the quotations and array keys so try the following

```
while ($raekke = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat))
{

    if ($antal_raekker == 0){
        echo "Der er ingen fotos at vise!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img src='fotos/".$raekke['fotonavn']."' alt='fotos/".$raekke['fotonavn']."' width='75px' height='75px' title='".$raekke['titel']."' /><br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok now we're getting some where :). Below is the error that is messing with your code:

> **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant fotonavn - assumed
>   'fotonavn' in **/home/mmd4a201105/public_html/galleri3/index.php**
>   on line **76**

It's actually pretty lucky that any of the image tags are showing-up because the one that is showing-up is part of an error message.

If you are trying to access the `fotonavn` index of the `$raekke` array then you will need quotes around `"fotonavn"`, like this:

```
echo "<img src=\"fotos/{$raekke['fotonavn']}\" alt=\"fotos/{$raekke['fotonavn']}\" width=\"75px\" height=\"75px\" title=\"{$raekke['titel']}\" /><br><br>";
```

If you don't use quotes then PHP thinks you are trying to use a constant rather than a string.

Notice I wrapped your array in brackets `{}` which is necessary if you want to add an array variable to a string, you can also do this:

```
echo "<img src=\"fotos/" . $raekke['fotonavn'] . "\" alt=\"fotos/" . $raekke['fotonavn'] . "\" width=\"75px\" height=\"75px\" title=\"" . $raekke['titel'] . "\" /><br><br>";
```

Which concocts the string using period (`.`) characters. I also noticed that the `title` attribute on your `<img>` tags needs a closing double-quote (`"`) which I added to the above code.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Your help is very appreciated.
Yea, it would've been wise to check the source code first, I see that... It was very helpful to me thanks a lot.
Now the gallery works, but the thumbnails don't seem to float left.... They're arranged in some kind of diagonal line... Do you have any idea what might cause this issue?
Is it something in the css perhaps?

Comment: @user1100686 I can't say for sure but it looks like the `<br />` tags are creating the "diagonal" effect. Try removing the `<br />` tags and see if that makes them line-up horizontally.

Comment: OMG I cannot belive this is finally working. You're a true genious man!!! Let me know if you come to Denmark some time, I'll owe a drink :DDD Thank you SO much, have an excellent evening!